# Referencing and VBA applications

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple question concerning references in excel formulas and VBA.

I am currently taking a course in asset pricing with applications in VBA. As I am very new to VBA, I have become very frustrated about a certain problem concerning solution sheets from my lecturer with reference to directories on his computer.

In the course we're gradually expanding a set pricing library called `analytics.xlsm` and as I understand this is a macro-enabled workbook. Within the project, there is a module containing pricing functions.

So, when I download my lecturer solution sheets all of the formulas containing pricing functions are referenced to a directory on his computer. As I understand, this is a 'link'. When I open the workbook, I have the option to change the link to my own `analytics.xlsm`.

I have tried this, among other things, but all I get is the `#NAME?` value in every cell referenced from or containing a function from `analytics.xlsm`.

I've tried the following in different orders and combinations:

- Enabling/disabling the `analytics` add-in;
- Updating the `Reference` under the `Tools` menu in the VBA interface to `analytics.xlsm`;
- Updating my lecturers link with the directory on my computer containing the pricing module.

I hope that someone in here can help me understand how this works. Ideally, I would just want to download his solution workbook with formulas containing only the function written in the pricing module in which case I could just load `analytics.xlsm` as an add-in. This works when I solve the assignments myself.

Example:

I want

```
=swaprate(..,..,.....)
```

instead of

```
='machintosh......analytics.xlsm!swaprate(..,..,.....)
```

I'm using excel for MAC and so is my lecturer. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this happens is that the add-in file containing the function `swaprate()` is local. In other words:

1. Your lecturer opens the file `analytics.xlsm` with his Excel; his Excel is using an add-in, let's call it `functions.xlam`, and this file is stored on his local machine: for example, `C:\Lectures\Financials\functions.xlam`
2. Your lecturer inserts the external function in a cell of the `analytics.xlsm`, for example he writes in `A1` the function `=swaprate(1,2,3)`.
3. Then he uploads the file on the web to let you download it. When this happens, add-ins are lost so the file `analytics.xlsm` (which contains the function `swaprate()` referencing to his local add-in) gets the originary source path `'C:\Lectures\Financials\functions.xlam'` before the name of the function.

So, technically (to test), the solution to update the link should be:

- After downloading the file with the now broken links, go to "Data", then "Edit Links" and update the source of the link to where *your local add-in* lies;
- Hence, you will now have the result as wished. Please note that if you're still seeing *your* local path before the function name (e.g. `'C:\Student\functions.xlam!'swaprate()`) it means that this particular add-in (lying on `C:\Student\`) is not active. You can activate it by Options/Add-Ins menu of Excel.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the cause of the problem. However, this did not solve my problem. I've done as you said and noticed the following:

The link in my formulars still persists and i've checked that it's the correct path, but still all the cells have #NAME?.  'analytics.xlam' (not .xlsm, sorry), is an active add-in.
If i manually delete the path name, and only keep my function name, the function works as intended and calculations are made.

I was wondering if perhaps my directory contains some illegal characters? It contains spaces, letters, punctuations and integers